# Как определить местоположение нажатой кнопки?

Tags: c#, windows, .net, winforms, button

Существует форма, на которую добавлены вкладки. Вкладки добавлены по умолчанию в конструкторе формы и их фиксированное количество. На каждой вкладке может располагаться несколько кнопок, которые генерируются динамически в коде и помещаются на форму. Исходя из этого, нужно как-то обрабатывать нажатие какой-либо кнопки, в то время как мы не знаем, с какой вкладки и какая именно кнопка была нажата. Подскажите пожалуйста, как в обработчике события можно определить, где конкретно на форме находится нажатая кнопка?

```
private void bt_Click(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    ...        
}
```

Comment: Ну, это можно, но вы делаете что-то очень не так. В code-behind какой формы находится ваш код?

Comment: `Click` и `PaintEventArgs`?

Comment: @VladD, отредактирую вопрос, чтобы вы поняли, что и для чего я делаю.

Comment: @Igor, пример кода можно, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте [FindForm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.findform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var button = (Button)sender;
var form = button.FindForm();
```

Вот [официальный пример](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.findform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).